# Concrete5 core blog thumbnail, How can I reuse it on other composers

Tags: attributes, concrete5

Concrete5 comes with package blog_entry by default.
This package includes image thumbnail with width and height restriction.
How can I reuse it with other types?
So I want to build a different Blog and use these thumbnails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a page type available to the Composer dashboard interface, go to Dashboard -> Pages & Themes -> Page Types, and click the "Composer" button next to the appropriate page type (then check the appropriate boxes depending on how you want this set up).

If you want to make some content fields available for data entry also, click the "Defaults" button next to the page type (in the "Page Types" dashboard page), then add a block to an area on your page, then click on the block and choose "Composer", and check the box to make it available in the composer interface.

The "thumbnail image" for the blog posts are utilizing an "image" block in the page defaults, so after you've enabled your page type to work with composer, go to the page defaults and add an "Image" block to an area, then I think you can edit that block and set some default dimensions. Before you exit edit mode, click on the image block and choose "Composer" and check the box to make it available to the composer interface. Now it should appear when you write new pages of the new page type in Composer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a custom template for the Page List block (then place the page list block on your blog "index" page, then click on the block in edit mode and choose "Custom Template" from the popup menu and pick your custom template from the list there).

Here are general instructions on how to create custom templates:

- http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/how-to-make-a-custom-template/
- http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/designers/custom-block-templates-views/
- http://concrete5studio.com/support/tutorials/creating-a-custom-template/

Note that as of Concrete 5.5, the markup in the Page List default template is much cleaner and easier to work with than what's shown in the above link. But if you're still on 5.4 or lower, I have cleaner versions of some block templates available here (this is actually what the newer version of the system template is derived from):

- https://github.com/jordanlev/c5_clean_block_templates

See the comments of those templates for instructions on including an image thumbnail specifically.

Comment: Thank you. I am using the latest version. but isn't that suppose to be done via Composer? what does the template got to with this? I want to use the core blog thumbnail in other composers. Thanks

Comment: Ugh... sorry, I totally missed that detail (it was only in the title, not the body of the question -- you might want to edit the question to make that clearer that you're talking about the composer interface specifically). I'll write a new answer.